# Is there a conversations.setTopic for Slack Notification plugin

Tags: jenkins, groovy, slack

I've been looking at the slackSend function that's part of the Slack Notification plugin, however I was unable to find a way to change the topic of a channel. Is there a way to do this with Jenkins?

I tried the following on my JenkinsFile:

```
pipeline {
  options {
    disableConcurrentBuilds()
    timestamps ()
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '30', artifactNumToKeepStr: '30'))
    timeout(time: 45, unit: 'MINUTES')
  }    
  agent {
    label "jenkins-slave"
  }
  libraries {
    lib('shared-lib')
  }
  stages {
    stage('Deploy stage') {
      steps {
        script {
          slackSend (
             message: "A simple test topic",                 
             channel: "xxxxxxxxx",
             color: "#00FF00",
             method: "conversations.setTopic",
             topic: "Build succeeded!",
             tokenCredentialId: "xxxxxxxxxx")
          sh 'echo'
          sh """
                curl --request GET --url 'https://api.pagerduty.com/schedules/xxxxxx/users?since=2022-12-25T22:00:06-0500&until=2022-12-26T22:00:06-0500' --header 'Accept: application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2' --header 'Authorization: Token token=xxxxxxxx' --header 'Content-Type: application/json'| jq '.users[].name'
          """
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I've also tried:

```
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        echo 'Building...'
      }
    }
  }
  post {
    success {
      slackSend color: '#36a64f', message: "Build succeeded!", method: "conversations.setTopic", channel: "YOUR_CHANNEL_ID", topic: "Build succeeded!"
    }
  }
}
```

And also this

```
pipeline {
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        echo 'Building...'
      }
    }
  }
  post {
    success {
      slackSend method: "conversations.setTopic", channel: "YOUR_CHANNEL_ID", topic: "Build succeeded!", color: '#36a64f', message: "Build succeeded!"
    }
  }
}
```

I am unsure if this function exists. Could someone let me know if there is a way to change topics on a slack channel within a JenkinsFile?

Answer (score 0):

I never used slack plugin, but you can solve this by using there API directly to change the topic [conversations.setTopic](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.setTopic)

and use curl to send the request in the pipeline

Comment: Yes, I am trying that out, I've having some issues with using the API at the moment as the recommendation is to use the http method here.